# How to convert Conv1d into Conv2d? [PyTorch]

Tags: python, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pytorch

Is it possible with `PyTorch` to use `Conv2d` to perform a `Conv1d`? The question may seem weird, but I need to use a tool that is not compatible with `conv1d`, but it works with `conv2d`.

What if I have `Conv1d(in,out, kernel_size=3, stride=stride, padding=1, bias=False)`?
May **unsqueeze** help me?

I have the same problem with `AvgPool1d (-> AvgPool2d) and MaxPool1d (-> MaxPool2d)`.

Answer (score 1):

A Conv2D is mostly a generalized version of Conv1D. You can of course use a degenerate version of Conv2D to reproduce a 1D convolution - 
You'll need to add in another dimension to the data:

```
data_pnt = data_pnt [..., numpy.newaxis]
```

You'll also need to specify the kernel size - You'll be choosing a 1D kernel - for example:

```
Conv2d(in,out, kernel_size=(3,1), <Other Parameters>)
```